# How in pandoc in one command (Windows cmd) to process a list of source files in Markdown located in different folders and glue them into one file

Tags: list, input, markdown, pandoc

I have many Markdown files. They are in different folders and each one has its own relative links to images.
files are in folders like this:

1. C: \ doc \ index.md
2. C: \ doc \ part1 \ 1.md
3. C: \ doc \ part2 \ 2.md
4. C: \ doc \ part2 \ more \ 2.md

To run the command, I use the standard Windows console.
I can use the command:

```
pandoc C: \ doc \ index.md C: \ doc \ part1 \ 1.md C: \ doc \ part2 \ 2.md C: \ doc \ part2 \ more \ 2.md -o mybook.docx --toc
```

but it is too long.
It would be great if there was an option to input a text (or other) file with a list of Markdown files, for example, **List1.txt** contains:

C: \ doc \ index.md 
  C: \ doc \ part1 \ 1.md 
  C: \ doc \ part2 \ 2.md 
  C: \ doc \ part2 \ more \ 2.md

And the command text would look something like this:

```
pandoc list.txt -o mybook.docx --toc
```

Does anyone know this is possible?

Comment: Ok. I find some decision. You can make cmd.exe command  like this: `/F "tokens=*" %A in (list.txt) do pandoc -i %A -o mybook.docx` but it not work for huge files with many char (limit of Windows console).

Comment: You'll have to write some kind of wrapper script... on linux/mac the easiest would probably be a bash script... but any scripting language should work..